# how to go to last page in cosmos db using continuation token

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using cosmos db from the front-end i am using angular material where i have option to go to last page. Currently, I am using continuation token from my API

```
  public async Task<CustomerProfileQueryResult> GetAllCustomerProfileQueryAsync(int pageSize, string continuationToken = null)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"CustomerProfile GetAllCustomerProfileAsync started.");
                int readItemsCount = 0;
                double charge = 0;
                string count = string.Empty;

                var customerProfileCount = await GetTotalCustomerProfileCount();
                count = customerProfileCount.ToString();

                QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.ConsumerName as Name," +
                                                            "c.id as Id, c.ConsumerID as ConsumerID ," +
                                                            "c.Addresses.StreetAddress1 as StreetAddress1," +
                                                            "c.Addresses.StreetAddress2 as StreetAddress2," +
                                                            "c.Addresses.Zip as ZipCode,c.Addresses.State as State, " +
                                                            "c.Addresses.City as City,c.Contact, c.Retailers as Retailer " +
                                                            "FROM ConsumerProfiles c ORDER BY c.ConsumerID");

                var customerProfileResult = new CustomerProfileQueryResult();
                List<CustomerProfileSkipTake> results = new List<CustomerProfileSkipTake>();

                using (FeedIterator<CustomerProfileSkipTake> resultSetIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<CustomerProfileSkipTake>(
                    query,
                    requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                    {
                        MaxItemCount = pageSize
                    },
                        continuationToken: continuationToken))
                {
                    // Execute query and get 100 item in the results. Then, get a continuation token to resume later
                    while (readItemsCount < pageSize && resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
                    {
                        FeedResponse<CustomerProfileSkipTake> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();

                        foreach (var result in response)
                        {
                            if (readItemsCount == pageSize)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            results.Add(result);

                            // Add the mapped object to the result
                            customerProfileResult.customerProfileResult = results.ToArray();
                            readItemsCount++;
                        }

                        customerProfileResult.Count = count;
                        charge += response.RequestCharge;
                        customerProfileResult.ContinuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
                    }
                }
                return customerProfileResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error in method CustomerProfile GetAllCustomerProfileAsync, for continuationToken {continuationToken} Error: {ex.Message}-{ex.InnerException}-{ex.StackTrace}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

[image]

If i click on last page i need to fetch the last page record based on page size

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos needs to iterate over every single item to know where to continue. So in order to get a continuation token for the last page you'll need to move over all documents first. Depending on the amount of items it's going to be an extremely expensive operation that could take quite a while complete.

There's a trick to this though. You could reverse the order of your `ORDER BY` to get the last page and reverse the order of the results in your own backend to generate a 'last page'.